# getting error "PG::InvalidSchemaName: ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in" while running docker-compose up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

i am using ruby on rails and postgresql for my project, here i am using two schemas one is CMS_DB_SCHEMA and another is SM_DB_SCHEMA for diffrent use case of my project so i have created dockerfile and docker-compose file as below

```
FROM ruby:3.1.2

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get --no-install-recommends -y install \
  g++ libpq-dev libpq5 libgeos-dev proj-bin libproj-dev \
  nodejs \
  redis-server

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY Gemfile* /usr/src/app/

RUN gem install bundler

RUN gem install sidekiq

RUN bundle install

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN ["chmod","+x","docker-entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh","docker-entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["bin/rails", "s"]

EXPOSE 3000
```

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  db:
    image: 'postgres:bullseye'
    restart: always
    # ports:
    #     - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: <%= ENV['DB_USERNAME'] %>
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: <%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] %>
      POSTGRES_DB: <%= ENV['DB_NAME'] %>
  app:
    build: ./
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
      CMS_DB_SCHEMA: "CMS_DB_SCHEMA"
      SM_DB_SCHEMA: "SM_DB_SCHEMA"
    depends_on:
      - db
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

so while running,

```
docker-compose up app
```

it is giving me some schema error like no schema is been selected so how can i resolve that.
[image]

Comment: Please share your error message as the plain text format!